# microsoft sql server 2012 express edition - limit of concurrent inserts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

Is there any limit on the number of concurrent inserts when using Microsoft Sql Server 2012 express edition ? I am aware that are limitations on the number of cpus that can be use, the 1GB of Ram limitation and the 10GB disk space limitations ([more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) ), but I want to know if there are any limitations on concurrency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it boils down to what you can squeeze out of it based on the other limitations/hardware. There is no "rate limit".

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx grep "Unlimited Concurrent DM Queries" there is no yes on the Express columns. There must be a limit!

Comment: @clyfe - that relates to Data Mining - note Express doesn't have *any* support for any of those Data Mining features. It's not talking about concurrent inserts in the OP's context

Answer (score 2):

There was some performance throttling in SQL Server MSDE but that was removed in SQL Server 2005 Express.

From [SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

> there is no workload throttle and the engine performs as in other
>   editions.

I have not heard or seen that it have been added again in later versions.